# Mongorestore based on ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore

I have two mongodb dumps weekly and daily. Daily dump is made for the last 30 days. What I'm trying to do is dump from daily backup based on last ObjectId from weekly and them restore daily dump to weekly.

I have this bash script:

```
#/bin/bash

echo "Choose date from list:"

s3cmd ls s3://backups/weekly/

read -p "Date (YY-MM-DD):" WEEKLY_DATE

read -p "Insert db name (e.g. staging.example.com):" WEEKLY_DB

s3cmd get s3://backups/weekly/$WEEKLY_DATE/$WEEKLY_DB.tar.gz

echo "Extracting archive ..."

tar -xvf $WEEKLY_DB.tar.gz

echo "Restore weekly backup ..."

mongorestore data/weekly/$WEEKLY_DATE/$WEEKLY_DB/

#get latest ObjectId from current weekly dump

echo "Get latest ObjectId from current weekly dump"

for h in localhost; do
    dbs=`mongo --eval "db.getMongo().getDBNames()" --host "$h" | grep '"' | tr -d '",' `
    for db in $dbs; do
        cols=`mongo  "$db" --host "$h" --quiet --eval "db.getCollectionNames()" | tr -d ',"[]' `
        for collection in $cols; do
            oid=$(mongo "$db" --eval "db.getCollection(\"$collection\").find().sort({\$natural:-1}).limit(1).map(function(o) {return o._id})[0];" | grep -e "ObjectId")

#dump from daily backup based on latest weekly ObjectId      
mongodump --host 192.168.0.1 -q "{_id:{\$gte:$oid}}" -d "$db" -c "$collection" --out daily

#restore from daily to weekly db         
        for dir in `ls daily`; do
               mongorestore --nsInclude "$db" daily/${dir}
        done
      done
   done
done
```

and I get this errors:

```
2017-09-20T13:12:57.218+0000    Failed: error parsing query as json: invalid character '}' looking for beginning of value
2017-09-20T13:12:57.228+0000    preparing collections to restore from
2017-09-20T13:12:57.228+0000    don't know what to do with file "daily/dbname/file.bson", skipping...
2017-09-20T13:12:57.228+0000    don't know what to do with file "daily/dbname/file.metadata.json", skipping...
2017-09-20T13:12:57.228+0000    don't know what to do with file "daily/dbname/file_data.bson", skipping...
2017-09-20T13:12:57.228+0000    don't know what to do with file "daily/dbname/file_data.metadata.json", skipping...
2017-09-20T13:12:57.228+0000    done
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do, particularly with the restore part of the script. Are you restoring the daily backup into a different mongodb instance, or are you trying to restore the daily backup to a different database name?